# Get jQuery element by stored data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using `.data()` function we can store data in jQuery objects:

From [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data1):

> Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of matched elements.

Example:

```
 // sets "string" value to "test"
 $(".myClass").data("test", "string");

 $(".myClass").data("test"); // returns "string"
```

This is simple.

Now I want to get all jQuery elements from page that have `"string"` value associated with `"test"`.

Is this possible? Is there any function that would do this?

Comment: do you have any other attribute like a class which is common to the targeted elements, otherwise AFAIK it is going to be damn costly because you have to iterate through each element in the page and then filter them

Comment: Another choice will to use a attribute instead of the data API like `$(".myClass").attr("data-test", "string");` then `("[data-test='string']")`

Comment: @ArunPJohny No, I know that. But I ask for `.data()`. It would be nice to be possible.

Comment: AFAIK there is no direct filter to do it, but you can easily write one if you are not worried about the cost using `.filter()`

Comment: @ArunPJohny You can post an answer. I don't really need it now, but it was one of my curiosities. :-)

Comment: done... see the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter the elements

```
var $filtered = $('<target-elements>').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('test') == 'test'
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YVLzV/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm affraid `.data()` doesn't actually add a `data-` attribute to your html element.
A possible workaround would be to iterate over the elements:

```
$('.myClass').each(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    if(el.data("test") === "string") {
        console.log("found !");
    }        
});
```

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5p9LX/1/

Comment: No, `.data()` doesn't add `data-` attributes. You can store any type of data. For example numbers or objects can also be stored.

Comment: @Johnツ Yeah I know it doesn't (that's what I said), check my edit it might illustrate my point a bit better. Having said that Arun's approach is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [jQuery.grep()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) to filter all elements

Get all elements with 'test' data key:

```
var arrElements = $.grep($("*"), function (a) { return $(a).data("test") != undefined; });
var $filteredElements = $(arrElements);
```

Get all elements with 'test' data value equals to 'string':

```
var arrElements = $.grep($("*"), function (a) { return $(a).data("test") == "string"; });
var $filteredElements = $(arrElements);
```